# Lowercase command output, rather than variable?

Tags: zsh

In zsh, suppose I want a UUID in lowercase.  `uuidgen` returns uppercase, so I can do this:

```
export MY_UUID=`uuidgen`      # get uppercase UUID
export MY_UUID=${MY_UUID:l}   # convert to lowercase
```

But what I really want is:

```
${`uuidgen`:l}                # does not work!
```

I don't even need a variable; just the output.  I created the variable only because I couldn't find a way to get and lowercase the command output at once.

Is there a syntax that allows me to get the lowercased output of a command in one step?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to have a variable. you can do:

```
echo ${(L)$(uuidgen)}          # nested parameter expansion
```

Or:

```
print ${$(uuidgen):l}          # history modifiers
```

From the web page reference:

> 14.3.2 Rules
>
> 1. Nested substitution
>    If multiple nested ${...} forms are present, substitution is performed from the inside outwards.

From `man zshexpn` (which is quite clear):

> If  a  ${...} type parameter expression or a $(...) type command substitution is used in place of name above, it is expanded first and the result is used as if it were the value of name.  Thus it is possible to  perform nested operations: ${${foo#head}%tail} substitutes the value of $foo with both `head' and` tail' deleted.
> The form with $(...) is often useful in combination with the flags described next; see the examples below.
> Each  name  or  nested  ${...} in a parameter expansion may also be followed by a subscript expression as described in Array Parameters in zshparam(1).

get to it with this command line:

```
$ LESS=+'/If  a .* type parameter' man zshexpn
```

And, for the history modifier expansions ( `${ … :l}` ) (emphasis mine) both [the zsh doc](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/) (extract below) and the `man zshexpn` contain the same text:

> 14.1.4 Modifiers
> After the optional word designator, you can add a sequence of one or more of the following modifiers, each preceded by a ‘:’. These modifiers **also work on the result of filename generation
> and parameter expansion**